# Rails 3.0 SSl for passenger on Ubuntu Natty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, ubuntu, passenger

I was wondering how to go about setting up ssl for a Rails 3.0 for passenger on Ubuntu Natty.

I have a rails book for 2.x, and it explains, as far as the app is concerned, that I need to install the plugin ssl_requirement. Then in my controllers use ssl_required for the specific actions I want to encrypt.  Is that still the same for rails 3.0?

Does any anyone know how to set up passenger to use ssl. From what I've seen it goes in my vhost configuration.

Appreciate any help.

Thank you,

Brian

Comment: Alright, I got ssl working for my domain. That was fun. Now I just need to know the proper way to set up ssl for a rails 3.0 app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, here's the deal. I purchased my ssl certificate through godaddy. Here's the steps I followed. I hope this helps someone because this was a pain.

1. pull up ssh
2. run openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout mykey.pem -out myreq.pem
3. download using sftp mykey.pem and myreq.pem from the directory you ran the previous command from
4. go to godaddy and enter the contents of myreq
5. download your certificates
6. place your certs in /ect/ssl/certs
7. place your private key mykey.pem into /ect/ssl/private
8. configure your vhost in /etc/apache2/sites-available/somesite for example:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName  somesite.com
      ServerAlias www.somesite.com
      DocumentRoot /root/public_html/somesite/public
   </VirtualHost>

   <VirtualHost somesite.com:443>
      DocumentRoot /root/public_html/somesite/public
      ServerName somesite.com
      ServerAlias www.somesite.com
      SSLEngine on
      SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/somesite.com.crt
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/mykey.pem
      SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/gd_bundle.crt
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
9. enable ssh: a2enmod ssl
10. restart server: sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
11. now if I haven't missed anything (it's 3 am) you should be able to pull up your site and enter https
12. go to: https://github.com/tobmatth/rack-ssl-enforcer
13. follow the steps there (I set it up so my whole app is https because I couldn't get it to work for individual actions)

I hope this helps. I'll look at this again when I wake up to make sure I didn't miss anything.